# How to remove an specific item from a list - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I´m a begginer in Python and I want to remove a specific item from a list, the removal criterion is that when an item contains the three firsts elements null it must be removed from the main list. This is what I´m trying to do:

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
temp = []

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        if a[j][0] + a[j][1] + a[j][2] == 0:
            temp = a.pop(j)
            print temp
        else:
            print a

        j += 1    
        i += 1
```

And I´m getting the following error:

```
    if a[j][0] + a[j][1] + a[j][2] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no idea what I´m doing wrong...

Thanks!

Comment: The `j` variable varies from 0 to 4 but you have only 3 items in list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to filter out sublists

```
>>> a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
>>> a = [i for i in a if any(i[:3])]
>>> a
[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

This basically works by using slicing to get elements `[0]` through `[2]`, then uses `any` to check whether there are non-zero values.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is this (range in this case is unnecessary):

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
newList = []

for i in a:
    if i[0] + i[1] + i[2] != 0:
        newList.append(i)

print newList
```

Comment: No, altering the list you're looping on (esp. removing items) will cause a similar error to the one the OP is observing.

Comment: It's not a good idea to modify lists that you are iterating over.

Comment: `newList = [i for i in a if  i[0] + i[1] + i[2] != 0]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Normally, I'd go for the one-liners too. I really think those can shine in situations like this; but he did say: _"I´m a begginer in Python"_. List comprehensions may just end up confusing him more for such a simple example. He'll learn about them soon enough.

Comment: @Eithos, I guess we won't use `filter(lambda x: any(x[:3]),a))` so either ;) Probably no harm to add the list comp while they have something to compare it to

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Speaking of things that *'cough'* don't work *'cough'*, `filter(lambda x: any(x[:3]),a))` is not valid code. I'll let you figure it out ;)

Comment: outputs `[[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]] ` so unlike yours mine is correct ;) should have gone to specsavers?

Comment: Strange. I get an `invalid syntax`. I don't know why, but it sure seems like there's an extra parentheses somewhere in there... :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to avoid the `any()` method call you can just use a [conditional check](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with the [`in` operator](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm).

```
a = [[0, 0, 0, 1],[0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 1]]
b = [i for i in a if 1 in i[:3]]
# [[0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```